# Android Glympse SDK Integration

Tags: android, glympse

After calling the sendTicket method for Glympse,

`glympse.sendTicket(ticket, WIZARD_FLAGS);`

Glympse SDK launches Glympse's default send wizard screen. Is there anyway to skip this screen with the current Glympse SDK reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User interaction is always required when sending a Glympse. SDK Lite comes with standard UI for populating and sending Glympses (Send Wizard mentioned above). It is not possible (and more over not legally allowed) to confirm it programmatically. [Commercial SDK](https://developer.glympse.com/comparison) provides higher level of flexibility with regards to customizing UI.

Nevertheless no matter which SDK you are going to use (Lite, Full or REST API) Glympse paradigm assumes user initiated sharing, so a confirmation of any kind is [still required](https://developer.glympse.com/cms/page/Developer-Guidelines). In other words it is not allowed to start sharing automatically without user confirmation.